# calculate the correlation between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I try to calculate the correlation between two columns, but it gets nothing.
This is a subset of my dataframe:

| Country | Energy Supply per Capita | Citable documents per Capita |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aruba | 10 | 0.004 |
| Andorra | 20 | 0.03 |
| Angola | 15 | 0.0007 |

```
df[['Energy Supply per Capita','Citable documents per Capita']].corr(method ='pearson')
```

Comment: It works fine for me. What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Check the datatypes of the columns to ensure that the numbers aren't strings.

Comment: `DataFrame.corr` was problematic until some version. You may also try `df[col1].corr(df[col2])` to use `Series.corr` instead. "It gets nothing" is insufficient explanation